# Numerical range of $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $(A_1,\cdots, A_d)\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^2)^d$. Consider
$$W(A_1,\cdots, A_d)=\{(\langle A_1 x,x\rangle,\cdots,\langle A_d x,x\rangle):x \in E,\;\;\|x\|=1\}.$$

> If $A_k$ are commuting, why $W(A_1,\cdots, A_d)$ is convex??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if $A$ and $B$ are two commuting $2\times 2$ matrices which are no multiples of the identity matrix $I$, then there exist $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $A=\alpha B+\beta I$.

WLOG we can choose $k\in\lbrace 1,\ldots,d\rbrace$ such that $A_k$ is not a multiple of the identity (else the *respective coordinate* of $W$ is constant hence obviously convex). Then $A_j=\alpha_j A_k+\beta_j I$ for all $j\in\lbrace 1,\ldots,d\rbrace$ and thus

$$
W(A_1,\ldots,A_d)=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_d) W(A_k)+(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_d)
$$

which yields the desired result as the numerical range of one operator is known to be convex.

Comment: Something is off here with your property of commuting matrices. Aside from the fact that you obviously can't add a matrix ($\alpha B$) and a number $(\beta)$ so I'll assume you meant $\beta\operatorname{id}_2$ a multiple of the identity; let $A=\small\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\operatorname{id}_2$. Then obviously $[A,B]=0$ but there are no $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb C$ such that $A=\alpha B+\beta\operatorname{id}_2=(\alpha+\beta)\operatorname{id}_2$.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. Please see proposition 2.4 in this paper: https://books.google.tn/books?id=lJbXcjpY4QsC&pg=PA75&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false   And let me if it is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Checking the footnote to Lemma 2.3 yields the original formulation of that commutation result: "If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix ($\neq pI$) then any matrix $X$ ($\neq qI$) which commutes with $A$ is of the form $X=\lambda A+\mu I$, where $p,q,\lambda,\mu$ are scalars and $I$ is the $2\times 2$ unit matrix." Of course if one of the $A_i$ is a multiple of the identity then the respective coordinate of $W$ is constant so we can wlog choose $B=A_j\neq\lambda I$.

Comment: If one of the $A_i$ is a multiple of the identity. Why $W$ is convex?

Comment: Well if $A_i=\lambda I$ then $\langle x,A_ix\rangle=\lambda$ for all $x$ with $\Vert x\Vert=1$ so this coordinate is constant (and a single point is obviously convex). On a side note, I proposed an edit to your original answer so it fixes the problem I originally adressed and hopefully also clears up this multiple of the identity argument.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. Thank you but my problem if for example $A_1=\lambda I$ and the others $A_k$ are not a multiple of the identity

Comment: Well in that case $W(\lambda I,A_2,\ldots,A_d)=\lbrace (\lambda,\langle x,A_2x\rangle,\ldots\langle x,A_dx\rangle)\,|\,\Vert x\Vert=1\rbrace=(\lambda, W(A_2,\ldots,A_d))$. As the first component of this vector is now constant, this problem basically reduces to showing that $W(A_2,\ldots,A_d)$ is convex (so you can "eliminate" all $A_j=\lambda_j I$ first) and for the remaining matrices, you use the $A=\lambda B+\mu I$ result as described above.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. It is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For nxn matrices A_1, ..., A_d, one may assume that they are in diagonal form
with A_j = diag(a_j1, ..., a_jn). Then it is easy to verify that for any
unit vector x = (x_1, .., x_n)^t, 
(x*A_1x, ..., x*A_dx) is a convex combination of the points: 
(a_11, ..., a_d1), (a_12, ...., a_d2), ..., (a_1n, ..., a_dn).
One can then check that W(A_1, ..., A_d) is the convex hull of 
the above points and hence a convex polyhedron.

Comment: Please format your answer using MathJax for readability.